# install software after HDD changed

Tags: toyota, maintenance, audio, navigation, software

how to install software on Toyota HDD Navigation (NHDN-W56g) after I've changed HDD? should I purchase it or can I dowload it and install using usb memory stick? thanks.

Comment: How about a little context? What was the old HDD, what did you replace it with? Why?

Comment: Its probably proprietary software that you wont be able to get hold of for a clean install. Do you still have the old drive? Did it fail completely or is the data still readable? I would try and plug the old drive into a linux machine and try and copy the data exactly as it is to the new drive, what are you trying to gain out of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure about your vehicle specifically, but there may be an update DVD that you can insert to reload the data. Talking to a Toyota dealership _could_ be helpful in acquiring one